Aerospike failedNodes: AerospikeException Timeout
I am getting this error while pushing data into Aerospike, anyone that has encountered this with and possible solution:
Aerospike Error:  Client timeout: timeout=0 iterations=3 failedNodes=3 failedConns=0
I am trying to create a cache using Aerospike and getting this error while pushing the data

This error effectively means that the node that should store the data that you're trying to "put" is not available. Typically this is due to a transient error and should rectify itself quickly. For example, if you have a 5 node Aerospike cluster and a node falls over as the data is being written to that node, the Aerospike Client Library will get a timeout error. However, in this case the cluster will "self heal" and typically within a couple of seconds the cluster will have noticed that node has gone down and designated another node to handle that data. Hence a retry after a couple of seconds should not see the timeout.
If you are seeing this happen constantly, do you have any network connectivity issues? For example, if you successfully establish the connection with the cluster and your network falls over you would likely see this error.
Which version of Aerospike are you running, and which version of the Aerospike Client? Which client language? If you can tell me a bit about your environment and cluster I may be able to help more. Also the policy settings you're using when you get the error, and if the error is occasional or all the time.

Sorry to reply so late, was experimenting some fixes
Here some of the details:
Aerospike version: 5.7.0.16
Client language: Java
Hosted on: k8s
Fails periodically: every 2 hours and 7 minutes precisely
One crucial observation was that the pods got scheduled on a certain node which was running other aerospike service and Apache solr pods seemed to terminate in the specified time frame (for all the services). After running cordon command to not schedule these pods and adding anti affinity rules, solved the problem to some extent. Would love to know if there is any reason for all of this.
